# Misleading use of the word "free" in the name of a product

Tags: consumer-protection, australia

Recently I received an email from crazydomains.com.au saying "Free Website Builder will Auto Renew in 1 day". Free website builder is indeed the name of this product. I have never used or wanted to use this product, but it was tacked onto my purchase of a domain name, and since it was seemingly free, I did not really care.
The next day I was charged 54 australian dollars for it. Is it legal in Australia to name a product as "free" when it is not free, and if not, what course of action might one take against a company that behaves in this way?